# Is the set of distribution $\{ X | \max_t |f_X(t) - f_Y(t)| \leq \epsilon \}$ convex, where f is the cdf or inverse cdf?

Tags: optimization, distance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, approximation, convex

I'm trying to figure out if the set is convex, where the maximum difference between cdf(or inverse cdf) of X and a reference distribution Y is smaller than $\epsilon$.

1.

Let $f_X(t)$ denote the cdf of $X$. $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Suppose all distributions considered is continuous

$\max_t |f_{X_1}(t) - f_Y(t)| \leq \epsilon$

$\max_t |f_{X_2}(t) - f_Y(t)| \leq \epsilon$.

Do we have

$\max_t |f_{\lambda X_1 + (1-\lambda) X_2}(t) - f_Y(t)| \leq \epsilon$

2.

What if $f_X(t)$ denotes the inverse of cdf? It is KS distance in this case.

For uniform distribution it is easy to prove, since the inverse of cdf are lines defined on [0,1]. But I don't know how to proceed with more general case.

$$$$

Eventually I'm wondering if this is a convex problem on $\lambda$

$\min_{\lambda} \max_t|f_{\lambda X_1 + (1-\lambda) X_2 }(t) - f_Y(t)|$

Any reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

I will use $F$ instead of $f$ for the distribution function.
Suppose $\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2$ denotes a mixture of the two distributions, then by definition $$F_{\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2} = \lambda F_{X_1}+(1-\lambda)F_{X_2}$$
If you know $F_{X_1}(t) \ge F_Y (t)-\epsilon$ and $F_{X_2}(t) \ge F_Y (t)-\epsilon$, then
$$F_{\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2} = \lambda F_{X_1}+(1-\lambda)F_{X_2} \ge \lambda (F_Y (t)-\epsilon)+(1-\lambda)(F_Y (t)-\epsilon)=F_Y (t)-\epsilon$$
Similarly, you can show $F_{\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2} \le F_Y (t)+\epsilon$

2.
Start by observing
$$F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon \ge F_{X_1}^{-1}(t) \ge F_{Y}^{-1}(t)-\epsilon$$
implies
$$F_{X_1}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon) \ge t \ge F_{X_1}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)-\epsilon)$$
Similarly,
$$F_{X_2}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon) \ge t \ge F_{X_2}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)-\epsilon)$$
Now multiply the first by $\lambda$ and the second by $1-\lambda$ and add to get
$$\lambda F_{X_1}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon)+(1-\lambda)F_{X_2}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon) \ge t \ge \lambda F_{X_1}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon)+(1-\lambda)F_{X_2}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon)$$
Finally, use the definition written at the beginning to deduce
$$F_{\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon) \ge t \ge F_{\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2}(F_{Y}^{-1}(t)-\epsilon)$$
and conclude that
$$F_{Y}^{-1}(t)+\epsilon \ge F_{\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2}^{-1}(t) \ge F_{Y}^{-1}(t)-\epsilon$$

Comment: Could you explain a bit about the first equation? That seems to hold for mixture not sum.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted.  What do you mean by $\lambda X_1 + (1-\lambda) X_2$? Is it supposed to be a weighted average of the two random variables and do you assume the two are independent?

Comment: If it means the linear combination, then the answer is No. Take $X_1,X_2$ independent and identically distributed with the same distribution as $X$ and suppose $X$ is standard normal. You can take $\epsilon$ as small as you want, say 0.0001. The first two inequalities are true. But, $0.5 X_1+0.5 X_2$ is normal with mean 0 and variance 1/2. With $t=2$, the difference between the two distributions is greater than $\epsilon$ so the third inequality does not hold.